# Unable to call a function from int main() body

Tags: c++, arrays, function

This is the SUM function I've created, to handle the arbitrary number of integers.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int sum(const int numbers[], const int numbersLen){
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i=0; i < numbersLen; ++i){
        sum += numbers[i];
    }

    return sum;
}
```

I'm calling this function from the **int main()** but it keeps on giving the error

```
 [Error] invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const int*' [-fpermissive]
```

The main function is as below:

```
int main(){
    cout << sum([2],5);
    return 0;
}
```

I know the mistake is very naive and small but help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: `[2]` - I take it you know Javascript? Maybe Python?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to send an array variable to the function as parameter. Try this..

```
int main(){
    int numbers[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
    cout << sum(numbers,5);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You are trying to create an array literal via `[2]`, like some popular languages support. C++ however doesn't support such syntax. If you want to create an array to pass into `sum`, the simplest way would be like this

```
int arr[] = {2};
cout << sum(arr,1);
```

Note I also adjusted the size you pass into the function, there is no bounds checking in C++, so to pass a size larger than your actual array is asking for trouble.

Answer (score 2):

The error is from your function call:

```
    cout << sum([2], 5);
```

I think you want to pass the array with 5 values {2, 2, 2, 2, 2} to the *sum* function then it would be:

```
    int main() {
        int arr[] = {2, 2, 2, 2, 2};
        cout << sum(arr, 5);
        return 0;
    }
```

And one more thing in your *sum* function, it is totally fine to pass *numbersLen* as value so the `const` is removable. You should take care of the overflow of your *sum* function's returned value also.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem lies in the arguments in your function call. The correct arguments are:

```
int main(){
       int array[] = {1,2,3,4,5}; 
       cout<<sum(array,5);
       return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

The below given code will solve your problem.

```
int main(){
int arr[] = {2};
cout << sum(arr,1);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: And then will cause another when the OP has to figure out why the program is crashing or formatting the hard drive :/

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Examine the call to `sum`, carefully.